# character encoding issue in data from xlsx to mysql

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, xlsx

i have microsoft excel sheet with data. i tried to import it to mysql using php and navicat. every time mysql table having some incorrect characters. i tried to set utf 8 character set, uft8_general_ci but still having issue in data. my file can have any type of character which i safely wanted to import.

charset image is attached [mysql charset of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFt96.png)

i used this code in php

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('myfile.xlsx');

list($cols, $rows) = $xlsx->dimension();

$counter = 0 ;
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using mysql charset utf8 through mysqli resolve the issue.

```
if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: Having an incorrect encoding in your database connection will trigger many other problems. Make sure you've not been storing corrupted data for months.

Comment: utf8 covers all the characters of different languages i got. but i was setting it incorrectly. thank you for your comment.